# How to get data from marker snippet in Google Maps app?

Tags: android

As the title says, I am looking to get some info from the `snippet` of a marker. I used a `CustomInfoAdapter` to create it, to be able to make it longer. I would like to get just a portion of info, when the marker is clicked, so I would be able to use the info to implement an `If` to do distinct activities according to the info from the snippet.

The way i created the snippet:

```
String snippet = "Adresa: " + adresa + "\n" +
                 "Oras: " + oras + "\n" +
                 "Ora raportare: " + data_ora + "\n" +
                 "Stare alarma: " + stare_alarma;
LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.position(position);
options.title("ID: " + id + " SITUATIE: " + tip_problema_sql);
options.snippet(snippet);
mMap.addMarker(options);
```

The `adresa, oras, data_ora, stare_alarma` are retrieved from a server, so I cannot use the variable as it is, because it is used to add multiple markers, according to the database, thus changing it's value. I would need some way to get it from the snippet. The way it should work is: when I click the marker, If the `if clause` used on `stare_alarma` is `TRUE`, the app should do something, and other thing if it's `FALSE`. So, coming back to my question, how can I retrieve only the `string` from `stare_alarma` located in the `snippet`, so I can implement the `If` in the `OnMarkerClick` method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer by trying everything that came to my mind, and I discovered 
the `getSnippet();` command and I used it inside the `OnMarkerClick` method. As the method has the argument `marker` I used the command : `String stare = marker.getSnippet();` 
To get the result I wanted, only a portion of info (I know the possible values that `stare_alarma` could get) I used :

```
if(stare.contains("Nevalidat")){
            ....
        }else {
            ....
        }
```

and between {} I've added how the app shpuld behave.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this data in tag, when onMarkerClick get this tag

```
String snippet = "Adresa: " + adresa + "\n" +
        "Oras: " + oras + "\n" +
        "Ora raportare: " + data_ora + "\n" +
        "Stare alarma: " + stare_alarma;
Marker mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(PERTH)
        .title("Perth");
    mPerth.setTag(snippet);
```

**strong text**

To get this tag:

```
 public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

 // Retrieve the data from the marker.
  String data = (String) marker.getTag();

    return false;
}
```